# Бесплатно ли использование API яндекс карт

Tags: веб-программирование, api, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Я подключил api Яндекс карт на сайт для отображения местоположения компании, карта только помогает найти компанию. Прочитал про трафик, про то, что ПО должно быть открытым и т.д. но все равно есть какое-то недоверие и страх, что придет счëт через пару лет на миллион.

При получении ключа указывается телефон, остальное можно написать фейковое.

Как Яндекс отслеживает нарушения, можно ли в них случайно попасть?
Как разработчики поступают при надобности подключить карту на сайт? Цепляют на свой аккаунт или просят заказчика предоставить ключ?

Comment: ключ имеет смысл регать на заказчика, ибо это его продукт, ему и ключами рулить. если у вас сайт с посещаемостью полтора землекопа, то опасаться вам нечего. в худшем случае упретесь в лимит и сервис перестанет работать. По факту  число запросов, емнип, можно отслеживать в кабинете разработчика, где подключается апи.

Comment: у яндекс-карт ограничения еще человеческие, у гугла всё еще хуже

Comment: Если будет превышение по показам - увидите карту с наложенным серым фоном и надписью про превышение. `страх, что придет счëт через пару лет на миллион` - Договор подписывали? Тогда идут лесом

Comment: Менеджер сказал, что до меня разработчики сами ключ получали (наверно, на фейковую почту делали и не парились), а я получение ключа слил на заказчика, уже стал сомневаться, но ваши ответы мне придали уверенности, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При соблюдении [условий](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) можно получить ключ и использовать API Яндекс.Карт бесплатно неограниченное время.

При создании сервиса, изначально соблюдающего все требования упомянутых условий, случайно нарушить правила предельно сложно. Единственная такая возможность - суточные превышения лимита. В такой ситуации доступ к сервису блокируется до конца суток. При систематическом превышении лимита доступ к сервису может быть блокирован перманентно до приобретения коммерческой лицензии.

Случайного "счёта на миллион" постфактум быть не может. Сервис оплачивается по типу prepaid - оплачиваете год использования - получаете оплаченный коммерческий ключ.

При разработке можно использовать и свой ключ. Ключей вы можете создать столько, сколько надо, и блокировать их после передачи продукта заказчику, если боитесь утечки (то же самое может делать и заказчик). Но для конечного продукта правильно будет получать ключ именно заказчику на контролируемый им и полноценно оформленный аккаунт, чтобы при необходимости (забыл пароль) он мог восстановить доступ по личным данным или телефону. Предоставит ли он его вам для разработки или будет использовать на уже готовом сервисе - это как вы договоритесь.

Comment: Спасибо за лаконичный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

**Лимиты запросов к API**

В бесплатной версии JavaScript API и HTTP API Геокодера установлен лимит на общее число запросов. Запросы в считаются суммарно по следующей формуле:

число запросов в Геокодер + число запросов в Маршрутизатор + 5 × число запросов к Панорамам

Их количество не должно превышать **25 000 в сутки**, из которых количество запросов к HTTP API Геокодера не должно превышать **1000 в сутки**. В случае превышения установленного лимита по JavaScript API или по HTTP Геокодера следует перейти на коммерческое использование API, в котором этот лимит устанавливается тарифом.

Подробнее тут: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html

Comment: об этом уже читал, не совсем то, но спасибо